# Discord.py sending blank .txt files

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to output a lot of data to a txt file and send it over discord on command, the rest of the command works fine and there are no errors but for whatever reason, the text file that is sent is always blank even though there should be loads of data in there. here is my original code for this section:

```
with open("#PATH" , "w+") as F:
    F.write(f"name : {name}\n")
    F.write(f"xp history : {str(xp_history)}\n")
    F.write(f"date History : {str(date_history)}\n")
    await context.send(file = discord.File(F))
```

I later changed this to:

```
with open("#PATH" , "w+") as F:
    F.write(f"name : {name}\n")
    F.write(f"xp history : {str(xp_history)}\n")
    F.write(f"date History : {str(date_history)}\n")
with open("#PATH" , "w+") as F:
    await context.send(file = discord.File(F))
```

because I thought that perhaps it was sending a blank document because it never saved the data, but no change

edit: added the rest of the writes as requested,
name : string ---
xp_history : list of numbers ---
date_history : list of strings ---

Comment: Can you provide full code of the what your function actually does, I got no idea what happens before your text file is written, There could have some problems before that.

Comment: ive checked the data myself by printing it out, it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the wrong data in the discord file. There is no need to open it and even though the file is opened in Write mode, You can enter the path directly into the below code.

```
await ctx.send(file = discord.File("#PATH including extension"))
```

The path starts with your Current Directory. /